# Guarantee switching to a specific window in Selenium

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, java, browsers

I have googled and looked at this site for reference but all the answers I came across did not provide a guaranteed way to switch to a specific window.

---

I am using Java with Selenium and I trying to find a guaranteed way to switch between two windows (where the second window is from clicking a link that produces a pop up).

`driver.getWindowHandles()` creates a Set object and since the Set interface does not provide any ordering guarantees, how will I be able to switch to a specific window?

What I currently have is this:

```
public static void switchToPopUpWindow(By by) {
    driver.findElement(by).click();
    Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles();
    if (handles.size() > 1) {
        for (String currentWindow : handles) {
            driver.switchTo().window(currentWindow);
        }
    } else {
        logger.info("There is only one window open...");
    }
}
```

However, since the ordering is not guaranteed, it won't always land on the window that I want. How can I guarantee a switch to the pop up window?

Comment: I would take a look at the window title when you're switching windows.  If you know the title you're looking for you can use that in a loop to stop of the correct window/tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How To Work with Multiple Windows](http://elementalselenium.com/tips/4-work-with-multiple-windows)

Some browsers might order windows by the order of being opened, other in alphabetic title order. Suggested solution is to get the list of active windows **before** new is opened, and compare them afterwards to find the new one.

Consider subscribing to the mailing list, for valuable tips and occasional webcasts.

Answer (score -1):

This is the simple and best way to handle multiple window's.

```
public void Test(){
    String parentWindowHandler = driver.getWindowHandle(); // Store your parent window
    String subWindowHandler = null;

    Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles(); // get all window handles
    Iterator<String> iterator = handles.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()){
        subWindowHandler = iterator.next();
    }
    driver.switchTo().window(subWindowHandler); // switch to popup window
                                                // perform operations on popup

    driver.switchTo().window(parentWindowHandler);  // switch back to parent window

}
```

[For modal dialogue and popups Alerts](http://selenium-tutorial.blogspot.in/2012/08/webdriver-popup-alert.html)

Comment: This assumes that window handles are returned in the order of opening. As you can see from the link in my answer, it is not always the case.